# how to get calculated values(totalPriceAmt) from js to html in by using angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
Js

var myApp = angular.module("DataEntryApp", []);

myApp.controller("DataEntryController",function($scope) {

  alert("totalPrice?" + $scope.totalPriceAmt);
}

$scope.Add = function() {
      alert("Total amount commint:" +$scope.totalPriceAmt);     
};
```

Html side

```
<div ng-app="DataEntryApp" ng-controller="DataEntryController">
        <button ng-click="Add()">Submit</button>
        <span>Total: {{ totalPriceAmt }} </span>
</div>
```

I am not able to get the values `totalPriceAmt` in HTML side after clicking on `submit` button or I want to directly display `totalPrice` in HTML.

Comment: Putting the scope variable in alert doesn't initializes the value :), Try assigning the value like '$scope.totalPriceAmt = XXX;'

Answer (score 1):

there is syntax error
 function is defined outside controller

```
var myApp = angular.module("DataEntryApp", []);

myApp.controller("DataEntryController",function($scope) {

$scope.totalPriceAmt =10;


$scope.Add = function() {
$scope.totalPriceAmt =$scope.totalPriceAmt+10;
};


});
```

http://codepen.io/vkvicky-vasudev/pen/xOOBGq

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display $scope value in html, you need to assign some value to that. As i can see from your code , no assignment of value is happening.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("DataEntryApp", []);

myApp.controller("DataEntryController",function($scope) {
  $scope.totalPriceAmt = 10; 
}

$scope.Add = function() {
   $scope.totalPriceAmt = 10; 
};
```

```html
<div ng-app="DataEntryApp" ng-controller="DataEntryController">
        <button ng-click="Add()">Submit</button>
        <span>Total: {{ totalPriceAmt }} </span>
</div>
```

Now if you run the app, after clicking the button , it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you must bind the variable using the ng-bind and then give access to the controller and use the $scope and perform the operation.

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error in your example for registering the controller with the angular application.  Fixing that, in the attached code snippet, you can see that I initialize the value **totalPriceAmount** to 0 in the controller, and then increment it by 10 each time the **Add** method is called when clicking the button.  You'll also see that the data-binding to the scope variable occurs correctly as well.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("DataEntryApp", []);

myApp.controller("DataEntryController", function($scope) {
  $scope.totalPriceAmt = 0;
  
  $scope.Add = function() {
    $scope.totalPriceAmt += 10;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="DataEntryApp" ng-controller="DataEntryController">
  <button ng-click="Add()">Submit</button>
  <span>Total: {{ totalPriceAmt }} </span>
</div>
```